# Closed Loop Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: matlab, control-theory

A system G(s) is connected with compensator K(s) in unity negative feedback. The closed-loop characteristic polynomial in monic form is given by p(s). Determine the coefficient 'B' of s. Give your answer to 3 d.p.

```
G(s)=(1.3s+2.5)/(0.6s^2 +2.6s+2);     K(s)=(s+1.6)/(s+0.5)

p(s)=s^3+As^2+Bs+C
```

Correct Answer:

```
 13.1333 ± 0.002
```

Another question set by a lecturer.

```
>> G=tf([1.3 2.5],[0.6 2.6 2]);

>> K=tf([1 1.6],[1 0.5]);

>> Gc1=feedback(G*K,1);

>> Gc1 =

       1.3 s^2 + 4.58 s + 4
  ------------------------------
  0.6 s^3 + 4.2 s^2 + 7.88 s + 5
```

I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: and your attempted solution is what?

Comment: G=tf([1.3 2.5],[0.6 2.6 2]);

>> K=tf([1 1.6],[1 0.5]);

>> Gc1=feedback(G*K,1);

after this i ended up with a transfer function

Comment: if you can edit your original post it will be easier to see, the formatting in the comments section sucks

Comment: G=tf([1.3 2.5],[0.6 2.6 2]);

>> K=tf([1 1.6],[1 0.5]);

>> Gc1=feedback(G*K,1);

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution, just convert the resulting closed loop transfer function to the minimal monic realization via `minreal` (which in this case amounts to dividing both numerator and denominator by 0.6) and you are done.

```
>> G=tf([1.3 2.5],[0.6 2.6 2]); K=tf([1 1.6],[1 0.5]);
>> P = feedback(G,K) % negative feedback by default

P =

     1.3 s^2 + 3.15 s + 1.25
  ------------------------------
  0.6 s^3 + 4.2 s^2 + 7.88 s + 5

Continuous-time transfer function.

>> Pm = minreal(P)

Pm =

   2.167 s^2 + 5.25 s + 2.083
  -----------------------------
  s^3 + 7 s^2 + 13.13 s + 8.333

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

The B term is

```
>> Pm.den{1}(3)

ans =

   13.1333
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated